# Should we eat Persian food, Indian food or Ethiopian food for Purim Se'udah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The beginning of the Megillah mentions that Ahashverush ruled from *Hodu* - India until *Kush* - Ethiopia. But, the palace was in Persia.

So to best honor Purim what type of cuisine would be most appropriate - Persian, Indian or Ethopian, or some combo.

Please cite sources for your answer, not just your opinion because you like certain foods best or they're cheaper, or similar answers.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should eat foods that have been seasoned with [turmeric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turmeric#Culinary) since that particular spice is popular from India to Kush, but especially in Persia.

While some would prefer to make an Persian food like [khoresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khoresh), it is permissible to put turmeric in anything, even foods that are not associated with the kingdom of Ahasuerus (or Ahashverush or whoever).  You could put turmeric in foods as diverse as cholent, mashed potatoes, beef tips, or french fries.  You could even sprinkle it in your wine and say that it is "mulled".  After all, it's Purim!  You can do all kinds of nutty things and people will accept it (but they might not come back for seconds).

Answer (score 5):

As a commemoration to the שַׁרְבִיט הַזָּהָב that Achashverosh gave to Esther, let's have some sherbet, which [has its roots in Persian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorbet#Early_history_and_folklore).

Answer (score 0):

Litvaks should begin the meal with turkey (hodu). Chassidim should end with quiche (כּוּשׁ).

Comment: Why that pairing specifically?

Comment: The chassidish pronunciation of כּוּשׁ would be something like "keesh".

Comment: The litvak pronunciation of הוֹדוּ would be Heidu, not Hodu.